# Expected value of product of two uniformly distributed independent random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, covariance

What is E(XY), where X,Y ~ U(0,1)

i.e., Expected value of product of two uniformly distributed independent random variables? It is probably not 1/4? What is the exact value? how to derive the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, 
$$E(XY) = E(X) E(Y),$$
where $E(X) = E(Y)$ as $X$ and $Y$ share the same distribution. We have: 
\begin{align*}
E(X) = \int_0^1 x f_X (x) \ dx = \int_0^1x \cdot 1 \; \ dx = \frac{x^2}{2} \Bigg|_0^1 = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$
E(XY) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}.
$$
Alternatively, define the joint density, 
$$f_{X,Y} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the densities multiply:
$$f_{X,Y} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = f_X (x) f_Y (y).$$
The densities of $X,Y \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ is $1$, so 
$$f_{X,Y} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 1.$$ 
Hence, by LOTUS:
\begin{align*}
E(XY) & = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 xy f_{X,Y} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \ dx \ dy \\
& = \int_0^1 x \; dx \int_0^1 y \; dy \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \\
& = \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}